# polymorphic dispatch from object-oriented programming with pattern matching

Tags: scala

There is this below paragraph from one of the book(book details below)I am reading for Scala. I am not able to understand what the author is trying to say. Can anyone provide more details about this?.

Book Details:

Programming Scala, 2nd Edition By Dean Wampler, Alex Payne. I am reading this book from O’Reilly Safari books app so I do not have the page number. This is from the very end of the chapter “Chapter 1 Zero to Sixty: Introducing Scala”

About Me:
I am working with Scala 2.11 for around 1.5 years and have some moderate experience of working with it. I would rate myself as 3/5 in my proficiency level. I am trying to read the book mentioned to improve my knowledge.

Snippet from the book:
“Hence, we have combined polymorphic dispatch from object-oriented programming with pattern matching, a workhorse of functional programming. This is one way that Scala elegantly integrates these two programming paradigms.”

Comment: Can you post the code snippet related to the paragraph? - Also, can you be more clear what you do not understand? Do you know what dynamic dispatch is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you might want to specify this information in your question next time, I assume you are talking about the *"A taste of concurrency"* section beginning on page 19, more precisely the ending paragraph on page 27.

Polymorphic dispatch, also known as dynamic dispatch, is one of the main advantages of object-oriented programming (OOP). It allows to select an implementation of a method to execute dynamically, that is to say at runtime.

Pattern matching is something neat you can do in functional languages such as Scala, namely to alter the execution of a method based on the pattern that one or more of its arguments follows (sort of like a supercharged case statement, if the labels could be much more detailed and involve type and other characteristics of its arguments!).

The Akka framework (which offers a Scala API) is used to obtain easy concurrency and is based on the actor model. Actors send each other messages, which are processed in an asynchronous, non-blocking manner.

Now that we have the basics down, let us examine the code to which the paragraph refers:

```
def receive = {  
    case s: Shape => 
        s.draw(str => println(s"ShapesDrawingActor: $str"))
        sender ! Response(s"ShapesDrawingActor: $s drawn")
    case Exit => 
        println(s"ShapesDrawingActor: exiting...") 
        sender ! Finished 
    case unexpected => 
        val response = Response(s"ERROR: Unknown message: $unexpected"
        println(s"ShapesDrawingActor: $response") 
        sender ! response
}
```

The receive method of an actor in Akka is called everytime it receives a message from another actor. A message can be of any class (e.g. String, Double, or even your own class). When this happens, pattern matching is first used (see the case labels?) to execute code depending on the type (class) of the message.

If the actor receives a message of class Shape, the first line after the Shape case label then calls the Shape instance's draw method. If the class of the message at runtime is actually a subclass of Shape (it inherits from Shape), dynamic (polymorphic) resolution is then used to decide which implementation of the draw method to call.

We could attain the same result using only one of these two techniques, at the expense of having to write a lot more code needlessly.

Comment: Thank you @David. This gave me a good explanation And marked it as an Answer. I knew about Dynamic dispatch and pattern matching. I never know polymorphic dispatch is same as dynamic dispatch.